# Editing WinForms ListViewItem programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a `System.Windows.Forms.ListView` declared `private System.Windows.Forms.ListView listViewContent` in a designer class.

I'm trying to **edit some properties** of a `ListViewItem`:

- `ListViewItem.Text`
- `ListViewItem.Tooltip`

The item I'm trying to edit is part of a `ListViewItemCollection` (`ListView.Items`).

Here is my first attempt to edit these properties:

```
int index = listViewContent.SelectedIndices[0];
listViewContent.Items[index].Text           = "Toto1";
listViewContent.Items[index].ToolTipText    = "Toto2";
```

The values of Text and ToolTipText **remain unchanged after executing the code bellow**.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Because of the non-modification of these values, I suspected the properties from being readonly, which isn't:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Gets or sets the text of the item.
//
// Returns:
//     The text to display for the item. This should not exceed 259 characters.
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
[Localizable(true)]
[SRCategoryAttribute("CatAppearance")]
public string Text { get; set; }

//
// Summary:
//     Gets or sets the text shown when the mouse pointer rests on the System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.
//
// Returns:
//     The text shown when the mouse pointer rests on the System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.
[DefaultValue("")]
[SRCategoryAttribute("CatAppearance")]
public string ToolTipText { get; set; }
```

I also tried this approach:

```
int index = listViewContent.SelectedIndices[0];
ListViewItem item = listViewContent.Items[index];
item.Text           = "Toto1";
item.ToolTipText    = "Toto2";
```

With this second approach, I can see that the **modifications applied** on `item` **are effective**:

[image: Second approach]

But **I found no way to apply these modifications to the item in the collection**. I tried:

```
int index = listViewContent.SelectedIndices[0];
ListViewItem item = listViewContent.Items[index];
item.Text           = "Toto1";
item.ToolTipText    = "Toto2";
listViewContent.Items[index] = item; // <------ What I tried
```

But an exception is thrown on `listViewContent.Items[index] = item;`:

[image: System.InvalidOperationException:Cannot modify the items collection in a virtual ListView.]

My guess is that the **ListView is in a particular state** (Virtual ListView) which **prevents me from modifying its items**.

But then, why can `ListViewItem.BeginEdit()` edit the Text property of the item?
I know that `ListViewItem.BeginEdit()` requires to set `listViewContent.LabelEdit` to `true` (I tried to set this property to true in my first and second approach, but it had no effect).

My question is:
*Am I missing something in the `ListViewItem` property edition process?*

Comment: _"In Virtual mode, the normal Items collection is unused. Instead, ListViewItem objects are created dynamically as the ListView requires them."_

Comment: First, what @stuartd said.  Second.. if you have a finite number of items in the list view, don't make the ListView virtual.  It will only complicate things.  You will know when you need to make the view virtual because loading the thing will suck.

Comment: So it seems my ListView is virtual. I'm working on a code I didn't write and I'm not sure I can modify how the ListView behaves